# Change the location of a specific data from a data output

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want Benjamin Netanyahu to be at the top of the list, how do you do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person_election` AS
SELECT
  SUBSTR(CAST(date AS string), 1, 8) AS date,
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
FROM
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY
  date,
  person
ORDER BY
  ???
LIMIT
  50;
```

Comment: Vote for him ?…

Answer (score 2):

Hope below example will help you with your homework

Assume I have some data that I want to output ordered by name. So I do below

```
select *
from data 
order by name
```

with output

[image]

Now let's assume I want Google Cloud to always be on top - so I am using below trick

```
select *
from data 
order by if(name = 'Google Cloud', '1', '2') || name
```

and output is

[image]

Hope, above gives yo really good idea on how to proceed with your stuff